# How to validate brackets with * equation string in PHP

Tags: php, string, validation, math

```
()*  -> In-valid
()(* -> valid
*)() -> valid
()** -> valid
)(   -> In-valid
)*   -> In-valid
```

I tried and stuck to implement the code, as I know that we have to do with Stack, but I just stuck there, can someone PHP expert one did it and :) and explain it.

- Input would be the string like "()*".
- "*" can used as open,close parenthesis
- open(left) parenthesis should have close (right) parenthesis in a valid expression.

I tried to do it with following code don't know my direction was right or not :)

```
$scenario = "()*";
$stackOne = str_split($scenario);
$stackTwo = array();
$counter = 1;
function push(array $arr, ?string $value)
{
    $arr[] = $value;
    return $arr;
}

function pop(array $arr)
{
    $count = count($arr) -1;
    if ($count > 0) unset($arr[$count]);
    return $arr;
}

function isValid(array $arr,string $value)
{
    $mapping= [
        "*" => ["(", ")", "*"],
        "(" => ["*", ")"],
        ")" => ["*", "("],
    ];
    if (empty($arr)) return "push";
    dd($arr[count($arr) - 1]);
    if(in_array($arr[count($arr) - 1] ,$mapping[$value])) return "pop";
}

foreach ($stackOne as $key => $value) {
    $output = isValid($stackTwo, $value);
    if ($output === "push") {
        $stackTwo = push($stackTwo, $value);
    } elseif ($output === "pop") {
        $stackTwo = pop($stackTwo);
    }
}

print_r($stackTwo);
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this? How is something valid or invalid?

Comment: I just added more info, let me know if it still requires more explanation...

Comment: Understood. So, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @nice_dev I added the code that I'm trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Interesting attempt but I presume there is a far simpler way to do this without needing stack. Can `*` also be considered as empty space value, or can it be only substituted as `(` or `)` ?

Comment: What about if you have multiple nesting levels? For example: `(()())`? Should that be valid or invalid?

Comment: yup, * can also be consider as empty space.

Comment: yes, It's a valid @KevinY.

Comment: `(()())` it's valid, because of in math it a valid every open parenthesis has close parenthesis as well, but if we change the order than would be in-valid like `)()()(` .@KevinY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for balance validity with 4 conditions:

- If there is a `)`, we should have at least 1 `(` or `*` in our account so far, both would work.
- If there are enough `*` for `(` to be paired with `)`.
- If there are still any `*` left, we can either use them as `(` and `)` pair or use them as empty spaces. Here, whether the leftover count is even or odd won't matter since we can substitute them as empty space.
- There could be leftover open braces at the end. For this to be balanced, we need to have `*` after them to pair them with `)`. So, we do another run in the end to check for it's validity.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function isValid($str){
    $star = 0;
    $open = [];
    $len = strlen($str);
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i){
        if($str[ $i ] == ')'){
            if(count($open) > 0) array_pop($open);
            elseif($star > 0) $star--;
            else return false;
        }elseif( $str[ $i ] == '('){
            array_push($open, $i);
        }else{
            $star++;
        }
    }
    
    if(count($open) === 0) return true;
    // check leftover open braces from the back
    $star = $ptr = 0;
    $open = array_reverse($open);
    
    for($i = $len - 1; $i >= 0 && $ptr < count($open); --$i){
        if($str[ $i ] == '*'){
            $star++;
        }else if($i == $open[ $ptr ]){
            if($star == 0) return false;
            $star--;
            $ptr++;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/58254)

Comment: Very creative counting star and open separately. Looks bullet-proof returning false as soon as a negative value is detected. Nice job!

Comment: @KevinY Thanks, appreciate it. I am glad my code is readable and accurate.

Comment: I think there's one edge case to double check: `**)(` you're counting stars, but need to double check they are in the right place.

Comment: Should be able to apply the same logic in reverse to fix the edge case: [link](https://onlinephp.io?s=zVPLioNAEDyv4D80QbBbDQSvxuxf7CWERcyECInKzJhLyL9vzyuv3UP2sqygXVZXNeU0Lt_H_RhHcZRoobSCGtZx9JYiZWnhAHqUEVLgMs8R-hrUSF6TZdceBjUakthMhiMykHtxtKlMgt0gRdPu0SdpFFjUNkrQmf2i3Q83qoAZ1CuYFXBq5Od2Oo7YqY_m0G3xZiMefLGzp77V3dDDVaO0NFOBr2QYRc9fzlwjuS4qzx8szUoGzuE77smBMemsAbguraGCPE-6MNpc3c5610azgbqGlNL7ftDYFCtYkAs0n1ePGnFQws3ilE5n4I86kEJPsoddwy93_YsfAk-J8FsimyHPn73PKpPgUeXg5f6grqmXbiydH_N5sclUugOX4oRctLRHV6w5YL3icyv4ZoDphsIuXt9eGSy_W1z5_zZX_sHqXlya57ScROU2bn-4OPoC&v=8.0.21%2C7.4.30%2C7.3.33%2C8.1.7)

Comment: @NaumanIlyas Please take the updated code now and not the previous one. Hope it is readable.

Comment: @KevinY Yes, I did the something similar (updated my answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach than both the OP and @nice_dev's answer, namely to construct a lookup table once in case more than one validity check has to be done:

```
// Generate an array of all possible patterns with length from minSize to maxSize
function generatePatterns(array $chars, int $minSize, int $maxSize): array {
  $count = count($chars);
  return array_map(
      fn($value) => implode('', $value),
      array_merge(
          ...array_map(
              fn($value) => array_map(
                  fn($element) => array_map(
                      fn($item) => $chars[intdiv($element, $count ** $item) % $count],
                      $range = range(0, $value - 1)
                  ),
                  range(0, ( count($chars) ** $value ) - 1)
              ),
              range($minSize, $maxSize)
          )
      )
  );
}

// Generate an array of pattern & validity pairs (key = pattern, value = true|false)
function getPatternsValidity(array $patterns): array {
  return array_merge(
      ...array_map(
          function ($pattern) {
            $countOfStars = substr_count($pattern, '*') ?? 0;
            if ($countOfStars === 0) {
              $tests = [ [ $pattern ] ];
            } else {
              $tests = array_map(
                  fn($value) => str_split($value),
                  array_filter(
                      generatePatterns([ '(', ')', ' ' ], $countOfStars, $countOfStars),
                      fn($item) => count(str_split($item)) === $countOfStars
                  )
              );
            }
            $retval[$pattern] = false;
            foreach ($tests as $test) {
              $testPattern = $pattern;
              foreach ($test as $char) {
                $offset = strpos($testPattern, '*');
                if ($offset !== false) {
                  $testPattern = substr_replace($testPattern, $char, $offset, 1);
                }
              }
              $sum = 0;
              $runningSum = array_map(
                  function ($value) use (&$sum) {
                    if ($value === '(') return ++$sum;
                    if ($value === ')') return --$sum;
                    return 0;
                  },
                  str_split($testPattern)
              );
              if ($sum === 0 && min($runningSum) >= 0) {
                $retval[$pattern] = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            return $retval;
          },
          $patterns
      )
  );
}
```

Generate all patterns:

```
$allPatterns = generatePatterns([ '(', ')', '*' ], 1, 3);
print_r($allPatterns);

Array
(
    [0] => (
    [1] => )
    [2] => *
    [3] => ((
    [4] => )(
    [5] => *(
    [6] => ()
    [7] => ))
    [8] => *)
    [9] => (*
    [10] => )*
    [11] => **
    [12] => (((
    [13] => )((
    [14] => *((
    [15] => ()(
    [16] => ))(
    [17] => *)(
    [18] => (*(
    [19] => )*(
    [20] => **(
    [21] => (()
    [22] => )()
    [23] => *()
    [24] => ())
    [25] => )))
    [26] => *))
    [27] => (*)
    [28] => )*)
    [29] => **)
    [30] => ((*
    [31] => )(*
    [32] => *(*
    [33] => ()*
    [34] => ))*
    [35] => *)*
    [36] => (**
    [37] => )**
    [38] => ***
)
```

Build array of pattern / validity pairs from the generated patterns:

```
$patternsValidity = getPatternsValidity($allPatterns);
print_r($patternsValidity);

Array
(
    [(] => 
    [)] => 
    [*] => 1
    [((] => 
    [)(] => 
    [*(] => 
    [()] => 1
    [))] => 
    [*)] => 1
    [(*] => 1
    [)*] => 
    [**] => 1
    [(((] => 
    [)((] => 
    [*((] => 
    [()(] => 
    [))(] => 
    [*)(] => 
    [(*(] => 
    [)*(] => 
    [**(] => 
    [(()] => 
    [)()] => 
    [*()] => 1
    [())] => 
    [)))] => 
    [*))] => 
    [(*)] => 1
    [)*)] => 
    [**)] => 1
    [((*] => 
    [)(*] => 
    [*(*] => 1
    [()*] => 1
    [))*] => 
    [*)*] => 1
    [(**] => 1
    [)**] => 
    [***] => 1
)
```

Usage as lookup table:

```
$isPatternValid1 = $patternsValidity['(*)'] ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo "isPatternValid1 '(*)' –> $isPatternValid1\n";

$isPatternValid2 = $patternsValidity[')**'] ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo "isPatternValid2 ')**' –> $isPatternValid2\n";

isPatternValid1 '(*)' –> yes
isPatternValid2 ')**' –> no
```

Array of all valid patterns:

```
$validPatterns = array_keys(array_filter($patternsValidity, fn($value) => $value, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
print_r($validPatterns);

Array
(
    [0] => *
    [1] => ()
    [2] => *)
    [3] => (*
    [4] => **
    [5] => *()
    [6] => (*)
    [7] => **)
    [8] => *(*
    [9] => ()*
    [10] => *)*
    [11] => (**
    [12] => ***
)
```

Array of all invalid patterns:

```
$invalidPatterns = array_keys(array_filter($patternsValidity, fn($value) => !$value, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
print_r($invalidPatterns);

Array
(
    [0] => (
    [1] => )
    [2] => ((
    [3] => )(
    [4] => *(
    [5] => ))
    [6] => )*
    [7] => (((
    [8] => )((
    [9] => *((
    [10] => ()(
    [11] => ))(
    [12] => *)(
    [13] => (*(
    [14] => )*(
    [15] => **(
    [16] => (()
    [17] => )()
    [18] => ())
    [19] => )))
    [20] => *))
    [21] => )*)
    [22] => ((*
    [23] => )(*
    [24] => ))*
    [25] => )**
)
```